# 'Nobody' vs. 'No body'

Tags: differences

What is the difference between **nobody** and **no body**?

I believe that both have the same meaning.

**Nobody** can be used as a pronoun. For example,

> Nobody is going there.

**Nobody** can also be used as a noun. For example,

> They went from nobodies to superstars.

**Nobody**: one word only

**No body**: two words

Is all of this information correct?

Comment: I don't know why any body would use *"no body"* (two words) today. They're the same word; the spelling switched from *"no body"* to *"nobody"* during the 18th century.

Comment: Nobody would use 'any body' — it's one word, 'anybody'. Perhaps, you've (Mustafa) confused 'nobody' with 'no one', haven't you?

Comment: AoA.it's a confusion about meanings as changes when words are split!???

Comment: "No body" is a very good reason that somebody might not be charged with murder.

Comment: As a side note, "He became Nobody to a superstar." is not a correct English sentence. We would say something like: "He was a nobody and became a superstar."

Comment: Call me old fashioned but this is why I prefer to use no-one, anyone and someone in preference to nobody, anybody & somebody.

Comment: For more confusion, you should see [somebody](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYMO4f0AsjM)

Comment: The difference between "They found nobody" and "They found no body" is a murder ;)

Comment: @Luke Perhaps if Madonna started calling him "Nobody", then he would have become Nobody to a superstar (which, somewhat ironically, would mean that he was no longer "a nobody").

Answer (score 57):

They do not have the same meaning in modern English.

There is **nobody** in this picture:

[image: nobody]

where **"nobody"** is a pronoun meaning "no person" (definition 1 at [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nobody?s=t)).

Whereas there is **no body** in this picture:

[image: no body]

where **"no body"** means "not a *[body](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/body?s=t)*".

In this picture there are a couple of **nobodies**:

[image]

where **"nobody"** means "a person of no importance" (definition 2 at [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nobody?s=t)).

Comment: I would say that 'no body' means *the absence of someone's body,* whereas 'nobody' means that *there is no person.*

Comment: See also [this classic scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tMcBNfhkZ-4) from Young Frankenstein

Comment: There's also a joke based on this in Clue. "There's no body. Nobody. There's-there's nobody in the study."

Comment: My name is no body, am I in this picture?

Comment: @user13267 - Nope, your name is "user13267".

Answer (score 3):

***[Nobody](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nobody)*** (n.) an a single term meaning "no one"  dates back to the 17th century. ***No body*** are two distinct terms with just their literal meaning:

> - mid-14c., no body "no person noone," from Middle English no (adj.) "not any" + bodi (see body (n.)). ***Written as two words 14c.-18c.; hyphenated 17c.-18c. Meaning "person of no importance" is from 1580s.***

(Etymonline)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nobody%2C%20no-body%2C%20no%20body&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnobody%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20-%20body%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20body%3B%2Cc0): *nobody, no-body, no body.*

Answer (score 2):

***Nobody*** - No person; no one.  Not anybody of importance, authority, or social position. A person of no importance, authority, or social position (OED).

***No body*** - the absence of a body (i.e. exactly what it says!).

A verse in Randy Newman's excellent song, *Short People* (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sX6I2NrguAs), plays with the two meanings of ***nobody/no body***:

*"Short People got nobody ...to love."*

1. If you are short you will not attract anyone to love you ('*short people got nobody to love'*);
2. If you are short you have less of a body (literally, the size of your body) to love (someone with) ('*short people got no body to love'*)

Answer (score 1):

The history of the phrase/word has gone from `no body` to `no-body` to `nobody`, increasing in frequency towards the latter. They mean the same thing in their use both as pronoun and noun, for example "He would talk to no body, not even his father" is acceptable in the oldest style as a noun.

The pluralisation thereof is the same irrespective of style, but can differ dependent on the text. I think the "becoming nobody" phrasing is contracted from "becoming a nobody", i.e. becoming one of the (plural) nobody group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to explain it with some simple examples:

> Amabo created a health care that **nobody** uses

**Nobody** means: **no one, none, not a soul, not a person**

> Amabo said that he killed Tim Osman, despite what he said, **no body** was found

**No body** is this case means **no corpse**, or **cadaver**

No body has the same meaning as others of its kind like **no salt, no hope**.